# User points category = taxonomy term

Tags: taxonomy-terms, userpoints

Im using user points (module) to reward users whenever they create content on my site. Now, I`d like to start rewarding thise points within categories (Points categories).

The categories I want in my points system are to be the terms that is available in a specific vocabulary on my site.

Exampple:
User X creates a "node Y" and classifies it with "term A". In this case Id like to award user x 5 points in the "term A" category.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Ditch user points and download and install [Rules](http://drupa.org/project/rules) instead.

Make sure you enable Rules UI.

Go to user fields and add a field of type **Integer**. Example: Lets name it `Term A Points`.

**React on**: (under node) **After saving new content**

**Restrict by type: None**

Add condition >> (under node) Content is of type >> select your content type (If you want multiple, hold the Ctrl button on your keyboard to highlight the content types you want)

Lets assume your term reference field is called `hello world`

Add Condition >> Data Comparison >> node:field-hello-world >> (type the term name here)

Add Action >> Set a Data Value >> node:author:field-term-a-points >> (click on switch to data selection) >> Data Selector: node:author:field-term-a-points >> Click on OFFSET and put the points you want to award, ex: `5`

You can then use the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module if you want to hide the Term A Points field from users so they cant see it and/or edit it.

---

Then you can create another rule when Content is **deleted**, do the same except OFFSET `-5`

---

If you want to diplay a message:

Add Action >> (under system) Display a message on the site >> Type your message here. Ex: [user:name] you have been awarded 5 points.

Comment: Thanks, but I have over 400 terms, I can`t make a field for each of them. Any suggestions?

Comment: @EspenArnoy Yikes!!! nothing comes to mind at the moment. If something comes up, I'll let you know.